# A real-world controller example with Spring 5: Web Reactive

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I want to be involved in a reactive programming world with Spring. As I realised, [it gives me a choice between two different paradigms](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-server-annotation): the annotation-based (with well-known to us `@Controller`, `@RequestMapping`) and the reactive one ([which is intended to resolve an "Annotation Hell"](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12954)).

My problem is a lack of understanding how a typical reactive controller will look like. There are three conceptual interfaces, which I can use in my controller class:

`HandlerFunction<T>` (1) - I define a method for each specific `ServerRequest`
 which returns a concrete `HandlerFunction<T>` instance, then register these methods with a router. Right?

`RouterFunction` (2) and `FilterFunction` (3) - Is there a specific place where all `RequestPredicate`s with corresponding `HandlerFunction`s should be placed? Or can I do it separately in each controller (as I used to do with the annotation approach)? If so, how then to notify a global handler (router, if any?) to apply this router part from this controller?

It's how I see a reactive controller "template" by now:

```
public class Controller {
    // handlers
    private HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> handleA() {
        return request -> ok().body(fromObject("a"));
    }

    // router
    public RouterFunction<?> getRouter() {
        return route(GET("/a"), handleA()).and(
               route(GET("/b"), handleB()));
    }

    // filter
    public RouterFunction<?> getFilter() {
        return route(GET("/c"), handleC()).filter((request, next) -> next.handle(request));
    }
}
```

And, finally, how to say that it is a controller, without marking it with the annotation?

*I've read the Spring reference and all posts related to this issue on the official blog. There is a plenty of samples, but all of them are pulled out of context (IMHO) and I can't assemble them into a full picture.*

I would appreciate if you could provide a real-world example and good practices of how to organise interactions between these functions.

Comment: This is probably too broad as posed, especially because while the API is probably mostly stable, Spring 5 isn't even technically in RC yet (and Spring Security Reactive is still in major development).

Comment: _"reactive programming world with Spring ... gives me a choice between two different paradigms: the annotation-based and the reactive one"_ Should be something like "annotation-based and functional one". Both are reactive, only the annotation-based style has a classical controller.

Comment: I think whats being asked here is "how to organize code", particularly in the case of the functional model.  I struggled with this as well.  The sample code would have us declaring all request mappings (route's) in one long NLP style chain.  This introduces coupling between route's that have no need to be mentioned in the same class file, and if I try to create handler specific classes, their routes are stored separately.
The annotation based approach looks like it might address these concerns, but I've yet to get that method to work.  Even if it worked, why have a functional approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a real world example, but so far Is how I view some kind of organization on this:

https://github.com/LearningByExample/reactive-ms-example

Answer (score 2):

As far as I concerned:

`RouterFunction` is the closest analogue to `@Controller` (`@RequestMapping` precisely) in terms of new [Spring approach](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/22/new-in-spring-5-functional-web-framework):

> Incoming requests are routed to handler functions with a
>   RouterFunction (i.e. Function>). A router function evaluates to a
>   handler function if it matches; otherwise it returns an empty result.
>   The RouterFunction has a similar purpose as a @RequestMapping
>   annotation. However, there is an important distinction: with the
>   annotation your route is limited to what can be expressed through the
>   annotation values, and the processing of those is not trivial to
>   override; with router functions the processing code is right in front
>   of you: you can override or replace it quite easily.

Then instead of Spring Boot `SpringApplication.run` in main method your run server manually by :

```
// route is your route function
HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(route); 
HttpServlet servlet = new ServletHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
Tomcat server = new Tomcat();
Context rootContext = server.addContext("",
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
Tomcat.addServlet(rootContext, "servlet", servlet);
rootContext.addServletMapping("/", "servlet");
tomcatServer.start();
```

There are both reactive and non-reactive approach. It's illustrated on Spring [github](https://github.com/poutsma/web-function-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/web/reactive/function/Server.java)

Comment: thank you for the response, but I was mostly interested in how a controller looks and how to organise interaction between such the controllers. Your snippet brightly illustrates a mess that is going to be when we gather global/shared things (like `RouterFunction` is becoming by putting all stuff in one place at once).

Comment: thanks for the github link, but I really don't want to write all routing logic in the `main` method or in a method named like `configureGlobalRouting` somewhere.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i can suggest that i will be done pretty similar to ratpack framework that new spring similar to: https://ratpack.io/manual/current/spring.html#the_spring_convenience_class